# Break an array into its corresponding value

Tags: php

Break an array with its corresponding value. There is only a single element in the array. I would like to break it with its corresponding values.

```
$myarray =   Array ( [manufactured_at Sku status title detail nickname customer_id option_id entity_id storeids] => 2012-12-01 11:04:59 1235-2 0 abc xyz kubeczek pqr 27 3 )
```

**I want my result :-**

`$myarray['manufactured_at'] = 2012-12-01 11:04:59`

`$myarray['Sku'] = 1235-2`

`$myarray['status'] = 0`

So on

Comment: Base on your example, each have 10 strings separated by space. `$myarray['Sku']` will then be equal to `11:04:59` not `1235-2`. `status` would be equal to `1235-2`. Which isn't same as your desire result. Please clarify and add what you've tried

Comment: Yes, Please in right of array there are 9 values. Some values are missed

Comment: is [manufactured_at Sku status title detail nickname customer_id option_id entity_id storeids] your array key? do you want to divide this big key into small individual key?

Comment: echo $myarray['manufactured_at']. Which give result 2012-12-01 11:04:59

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an `associative array` than you need to format your code differently.

The syntax for an associative array is `$array = array($key1=>$value1, $key2=>$value2);`

If you're trying to get:  `$myarray['manufactured_at'] = 2012-12-01 11:04:59` then your array needs to be formatted like this:

```
$myarray = array('manufactured_at'=>'2012-12-01 11:04:59', 'SKu'=> '1235-2', 'status'=>0);
```